# How to create overlay screen with user instructions on app start

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which i want to create an overlay screen on first time application start only.I am using a fragment as home screen on app start.
I want to do it manually not by showcase library..

Comment: use should use a relative layout with match parent hieght and width .. >> make it visible at first run >> set Visible as you want

Answer (score 3):

Use one of these libraries:

- https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView
- https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo
- https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide

Example for showcaseView:

```
Button closeButton = new Button(this);
        closeButton.setBackgroundColor(200);
        closeButton.setEnabled(false);

        showcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(new PointTarget(330, 570))
//                .setTarget(new ViewTarget(((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)).getChildAt(0)))//works
                .setContentTitle("Add a new device")
                .setContentText("You need to add a new device to be able to use this app")
//                .hideOnTouchOutside()
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                .replaceEndButton(closeButton)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i follow your question than, You should use a `RelativeLayout` as overlay. and set visibility according to your need.

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout>

// your main layout goes here

<LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/overlay"
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Dev Kumar ...upvoting and accept the answer is the way to say thanks on #StackOverFlow.